# Oracle throws ORA-12514 after shutdown immediate

Tags: oracle12c

My goal is to get my container database into a mount mode to execute a system alter statement to enable flashback functions.

[Configuring Your Database for Flashback Transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS611)

Environment: OS Win 8.1 64-bit, Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0) 64-Bit

I verified that both my listener and db service are running.

**Listener.log**

> Tue Sep 08 13:31:42 2015 System parameter file is
>   C:\OracleServer\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora Log
>   messages written to
>   C:\OracleServer\diag\tnslsnr\NA-D02979\listener\alert\log.xml Trace
>   information written to
>   C:\OracleServer\diag\tnslsnr\NA-D02979\listener\trace\ora_9672_20416.trc
>   Trace level is currently 0
>
> Started with pid=9672 Listening on:
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.1.105.118)(PORT=1521)))
>   Listening on:
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
>   Listening on:
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
>   Listener completed notification to CRS on start
>
> TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN
>   CODE Listening on:
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=NA-D02979.vgnet.volgrp.com)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\ORACLESERVER\admin\CDB1\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
>   Dynamic address is already listened on
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
>   08-SEP-2015 13:32:25 * service_register * cdb1 * 0 08-SEP-2015
>   13:33:22 * service_update * cdb1 * 0

**Results of SqlPlus**

> C:\Users\jeff>sqlplus sys/**********@CDB1 as sysdba
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Sep 8 13:44:18 2015
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
>   12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
>
> SQL> shutdown immediate
>
> Database closed.
>
> Database dismounted.
>
> ORACLE instance shut down.
>
> ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
>
> Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
>
> SQL> startup mount
>
> SP2-0640: Not connected
>
> SQL> ^C
>
> C:\Users\jeff>sqlplus> sys/**********@CDB1 as sysdba
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Sep 8 13:46:24 2015
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
>
> Enter user-name:

When I connect to my container DB as sysdba, I can issue the shutdown immediate command, but as soon as the database dismounts, the listener no longer knows about the database and I am unable to issue the "startup mount" command.

**Listener.ora**

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
>
> ```
> (SID_DESC =
>
>   (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
>
>   (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleServer\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
>
>   (PROGRAM = extproc)
>
>   (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\OracleServer\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
>
> )
> ```
>
> (SID_DESC =
>
> ```
>  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = CDB1)
>
>  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
>
>  (SID_NAME = CDB1)
>
> )   )
> ```
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =    (DESCRIPTION =
>
> ```
>   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.105.118)(PORT = 1521))
> ```

```
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

> ```
>   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>
> )   )
> ```

**TNSNames.ora**

> LISTENER_CDB1 =
>
> ```
>  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
> ```
>
> CDB1 =
>
> ```
>  (DESCRIPTION =
>
>    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.105.118)(PORT = 1521))
>
>    (CONNECT_DATA =
>
>     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>
>      (SERVICE_NAME = CDB1.vgnet.volgrp.com)
>
>    )
>
>  )
> ```
>
> ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
>
> ```
>  (DESCRIPTION =
>
>    (ADDRESS_LIST =
>
>      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>
>    )
>
>    (CONNECT_DATA =
>
>      (SID = CLRExtProc)
>
>      (PRESENTATION = RO)
>
>    )
>
>  )
> ```

I have defined a static SID to my container database.

**Second Round Results**

From the following results, I followed what Alex Pool had documented in the answer. I am on the same machine as the database. I have set ORACLE_SID to cdb1, then every time I try to connect, I am getting a ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error. Why is my listener still throwing TNS errors when I am trying to connect based on SID?

```
C:\Users\jeff>%ORACLE_SID%
'cdb1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\jeff>sqlplus sys/********** as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Sep 9 08:05:25 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Enter user-name: ^C
C:\Users\jeff>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Sep 9 08:05:36 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Enter user-name: ^C
C:\Users\jeff>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Sep 9 08:05:50 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

SQL>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The listener no longer knows about the *service* because the database has unregistered itself during shutdown. It still knows about the SID, though that isn't very useful. You can `lsnrctl status` before and after the shutdown to see the difference.

You said you have defined a static SID, which is true (assuming you're referring to the `SID_LIST_LISTENER` entries), but you're connecting using the `@CDB1` TNS alias, which is defied in your `tnsnames.ora` to use the service name, not the SID. You may be slightly confused by having the same value as the alias and the SID, but there is no direct relation between them; you could have called the alias something completely different (though it's common to have them the same).

If you're connecting from the same box, set `ORACLE_SID` to `CDB1` and connect locally rather than over SQL*Net, with just:

```
sqlplus sys/********** as sysdba
```

Or even

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Or

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
```

Comment: I have performed the steps you described but still getting Listener errors. I have added my testing results to my question.

Comment: @JeffP. - if you're connecting like this then you don't go through TNS or the listener. Unless you have TWO_TASK set as well as/instead of ORACLE_SID. (Er, or on Windows... I think the equivalent of TWO_TASK is LOCAL?)

Comment: @JeffP. - is `%LOCAL%` set in your environment? I hadn't entirely registered any significance in your being on 12c, [but this should still work for a container DB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_admin.htm#ADMIN13608).

Comment: I checked LOCAL and it was not defined. Just for kicks I did check TWO_TASK (even though it's supposed to be used by Unix). So I did check my ORACLE_SID environment variable to cdb1. I was then able to connect. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

$ export TWO_TASK =

sqlplus /nolog

conn sys/pass as sysdba